# DBus Send from shell

Tags: linux, shell, dbus

I need to send a method call with DBus from shell

when i send this code from shell :

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --type=method_call \
--dest=vehicle.network.service /Diag \
vehicle.network.service.Diag.setVariantCoding
```

I got this reply :

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '()', does not match expected type '(uay)'

how i can i make the message type as (uay)?

i know it is 6 bytes long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is automatically determined from the arguments (parameters) that you provide.

`(uay)` means you need to provide an uint32 (`u`) and a byte-array (`ay`) to this specific method. (The [D-Bus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system) explains the meaning of the type notation.)

For example, if you want to call `setVariantCoding(12345, "\xAB\xCD\xEF")`, use:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call \
          --dest=vehicle.network.service \
          /Diag \
          vehicle.network.service.Diag.setVariantCoding \
          uint32:12345 array:byte:0xAB,0xCD,0xEF
```

With `gdbus`:

```
gdbus call -y -d vehicle.network.service \
              -o /Diag \
              -m vehicle.network.service.Diag.setVariantCoding \
              "@u 12345" "@ay [0xAB,0xCD,0xEF]"
```

With `busctl`:

```
busctl call --system \
            vehicle.network.service \
            /Diag \
            vehicle.network.service.Diag \
            setVariantCoding \
            uay 12345 3 0xAB 0xCD 0xEF
```

(In busctl, the array length is specified explicitly, using `3` in this example.)

Comment: Awesome!
Thank you